# Getting error loading data into the MS Access using SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

Message
Executed as user: WORKGROUP\REPORTING$. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  4:10:44 PM  Error: 2013-06-26 16:10:45.69     Code: 0xC0209303     Source: WAP_Success_DUMP Connection manager "SAME"     Description: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error: 2013-06-26 16:10:45.69     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: ALL OLE DB Destination [173]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SAME" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2013-06-26 16:10:45.69     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: ALL SSIS.Pipeline     Description: OLE DB Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2013-06-26 16:10:45.69     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: ALL SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2013-06-26 16:10:45.69     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: ALL      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  4:10:44 PM  Finished: 4:10:45 PM  Elapsed:  1.528 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I am getting the above error ,when I executed the package using Sql Server job agent.When I execute the package using BIDS its running successfully.I have changed my solution to the Run64bitRunTime false I am getting the some other errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this before. I had to change the Run64bitRunTime property to false. Then make sure the appropriate driver was installed on the server. Ultimately I started using the ACE drivers.